Number of elevated paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n+2,0)$ in a lattice grid
What formula or recurrence relation, if any, counts the number of elevated paths in a lattice grid from $(0,0)$ to $(n+2,0)$ where the steps are $U=(1,1), H=(1,0)$, and $D=(1,-1)$ ? The term elevated in this context means that each such path remains strictly above the $x$-axis except for the initial vertex of $(0,0)$ and the final vertex of $(n+2,0)$.
In particular, how many such paths exist for $n=4$ and  $n= 5$ (even if there is no general formula)?

I suggest:  define a "pretty good" word to be one that never goes below the $x-$axis and which start and stops on the axis, and a "very good" word to be one that stays strictly about (so that's what you are counting) except at start and end.  the point being that, since the first and last moves of a very good word are fixed, the count is the same as the number of pretty good words of length $n-2$.

Note too that, were it not for the straight horizontal move, pretty good words would just give you the Catalan numbers so your pretty good words can be written as a weighted sum of Catalan numbers (as you can intersperse as many horizontal moves as needed to top off the length).  Probably not the best way to count the pretty good words in general, but it would certainly work for small $n$.

The goal of this question is to identify a precise formula for the exact number of such paths for any value of n. I need a precise formula to count the pretty good words for all n, rather than an approximation.

Nobody has mentioned an approximation.  The method I sketched is exact.  Of course, since it's a weighted sum of Catalan numbers, the summation won't be pretty.  It's possible that there is a simpler formula but, regardless of that, I suggest implementing the scheme I described.  It will work fine for modest $n$ so, in particular, it covers the cases you mentioned (though you should easily be able to handle such small cases by hand).  And it will produce the first $20$ or so values of your sequence without much fuss, at which point perhaps you or Oeis.org will recognize it

@lulu See Wikipedia on Motzkin paths.

@JeanMarie  Somewhat surprised to see that my Catalan number method is pretty much as good as it gets.

The first step must be an $U$, and the last step must be a $D$, so we can just consider the middle $n$ steps from $(1, 1)$ to $(n+1, 1)$.
Then, if we translate all points by $(-1, -1)$, we obtain an equivalent problem formulation:

What is the number of paths in a lattice grid from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, 0)$ where the allowed steps are $(1, 1)$, $(1, 0)$, and $(1, -1)$, and each path cannot go below the $x$-axis (but can touch the axis)?

This formulation is one of the combinatorial formulation described in Motzkin number on Wikipedia. (OEIS sequence A001006). The first few numbers are
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 21, 51, 127, \dots.$$
The Wikipedia page states that one possible recurrence relation for the
the $n$-th Motzkin number $M_n$ is $$M_n = M_{n-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}M_i M_{n-2-i}.$$
It can also be defined using Catalan numbers $C_n$: $$M_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} C_k.$$
